# Community String vs password - what’s the rationale behind the term name?

Tags: snmp, snmpv3

I’m just starting my learning of networking. The term “community string” refers to a type of password, Especially when it comes to sending/receiving configuration settings to/from a snmp server, correct?

My question is why is it called “community string” instead of “SNMP password”?

I understand for example why on the cisco iOS there’s “secret” vs “password”. But “community string” gives no clue as to why it’s called that way for me.

Thanks.

Comment: This is really just historical trivia.

Answer (score 3):

Because that's the name that [RFC 1157](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1157#section-3.2.5) gave it.

> A pairing of an SNMP agent with some arbitrary set of SNMP
> application entities is called an SNMP community.  Each SNMP
> community is named by a string of octets, that is called the
> community name for said community.

The people who wrote the SNMP standard are not the same people who wrote Cisco software.

Comment: Understood- I merely mention the Cisco iOS as an analogy, as in I understand why in that system the two synonymous words had different uses (encrypted vs not) but in snmp I found nothing else that serves the purpose of password. Your answer cleared it up though.